# Is my regex too greedy?

Tags: regex, bash

**Background**: We're using a tape library and the backup software NetWorker to back up data here. The client that's installed is fairly basic, and when we need to restore more than one target directory we create a script that simply calls X client instances in the background via a script with X of the following lines:

```
recover -c client-srv -t "Mon Dec 10 08:00:00" -s barckup-srv -d /dest/dir/ -f -a /src/dir &
```

The trouble is that different partitions/directories backed up from the same machine at the same time might be spread across several different tapes, and some of those tapes may have been removed from the library between the backup and restore.

Up until recently the only ways the people here have been finding out about which tapes are needed were to either wait for the library to complain that it doesn't have a particular tape, or to set up a fake restore in an crappy old desktop GUI client and hit a particular menu option. The first option is super bad when the tape turns out to be off-site and takes a day to get back, and the second is tedious and time-consuming.

**Actual Question**: I've written a "meta"-script that reads the script that we've already created with the commands above, feeds it into the interactive CLI client, and gets it to spit out what tapes are required, and if they're actually in the library. To do this, the script uses the following regular expressions to pull out necessary info:

```
# pull out a list of the -a targets
restore_targets="`sed 's/^.* -a \([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/' $rec_script`"

# pull out a list of -c clients
restore_clients="`sed 's/^.* -c \([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/' $rec_script`"
numclients=`echo $restore_clients | uniq | wc -l`

# pull out a list of -t dates
restore_dates="`sed 's/^.* -t \"\([^\"]*\)\" .*$/\1/' $rec_script`"
numdates=`echo $restore_dates | uniq | wc -l`
```

I am not terribly familiar with using `s/\(x\)/\1/` types of regexes, to the point that I don't remember the name, but is this the best way of accomplishing what I am doing? The commands *work*, but I'm wondering if I'm using the `.*` needlessly.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data you are reading from?  Maybe something with what you are actually looking for? I am looking at the Regex, but I can't figure out exactly what want to get without seeing a sample of what you are reading.

Comment: @Nick He's reading from a script containing lines like the one he quoted above, beginning with `recover`.

Comment: @Barmar wow, this is what I get for skipping coffee this morning.  I see it now.

Comment: Took me a minute to figure it out, too. But when I saw `-a`, `-c`, and `-t` in the regex, it became clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\1` refers to the first capturing group. If you replace `foo(.*?)` with `\1` and feed in `foobar`, the resulting text becomes `bar`, as `\1` points to the text captured by the first capturing group.

As for your your question, it might be safer and easier to parse the arguments using Python (or another high-level scripting language):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('recover -c client-srv -t "Mon Dec 10 08:00:00" -s barckup-srv -d /dest/dir/ -f -a /src/dir &')
['recover', '-c', 'client-srv', '-t', 'Mon Dec 10 08:00:00', '-s', 'barckup-srv', '-d', '/dest/dir/', '-f', '-a', '/src/dir', '&']
```

Now, this is much easier to work with. The quotes are gone and all of the components of the command are nicely split up into a list.

If you want this to be completely foolproof, you could use `argparse` and implement your own parser for this command line pretty easily. This will enable you to easily get the info, but it might be overkill for your situation.

As for your *actual* question, you can dissect the regex:

```
^.* -t "([^\"]*)" .*$
```

This regex captures `-t "foo \" bar"`, while a non-greedy version would stop at `-t "foo \"`.

Comment: It's actually `^.* -t "([^"]*)" .*$` [no backslash], it just needs to be escaped because it's being wrapped in `"`. I'd also love to use something like Python, but the script has to be able to run on HPUX machines, so any language/syntax newer than about 1984 won't work.

Comment: @Sammitch: Well that complicates things. If your current regex works, it works.